# What does this phrase mean? (old girlfriend)

Tags: meaning, phrases

"My hate for you is beyond measurable!"

Comment: It means she needs a longer tape measure.

Comment: Do you mean that an old girlfriend said this to you? The wording of the question is unclear. If she means that she really hates you a lot, a better phrasing would be "My hate for you is beyond measure."  "Beyond measure" is an idiom that means "a lot." "Beyond measuring" is likely either a mis-hearing or misuse of the idiom.

Answer (score 2):

It means she doesn't like you. In fact she hates you. She hates you an awful lot. Some people hate someone a lot, but the hate is still small enough that it can be measured. Her hate for you is worse than that.

It's what an ex-girlfriend would say if you murdered her whole family because she left you.